# Android: Set HorizontalGridView to wrap_content?

Tags: android

I am setting the width of `HorizontalGridView` to `wrap_content`. But it is not adapting itself according to its content. In below image white bar shows the `HorizontalGridView`. How I can achieve desired behaviour?

```
 <android.support.v17.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:width="wrap_content"
    android:height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:focusable="true"
    lb:horizontalMargin="@dimen/menu_inter_card_spacing" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
```

[image]

Comment: have you found solution?

Answer (score 2):

To achieve that I override onMeasure method in that way:

```
override fun onMeasure(widthSpec: Int, heightSpec: Int) {
    super.onMeasure(widthSpec, heightSpec)
    val widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec)
    val widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec)

    if(widthMode == AT_MOST) {
        var widthOnAdapterItems = 0
        adapter?.let {
            for (i in 0 until it.itemCount) {
                val viewType = it.getItemViewType(i)
                val viewHolder = it.createViewHolder(this,viewType)
                viewHolder.itemView.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec)
                widthOnAdapterItems += viewHolder.itemView.measuredWidth
            }
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(min(widthOnAdapterItems, widthSize), measuredHeight)
    }
}
```

it's not optimal but it works. ;)

Comment: It's not working but I didn't find a solution, the problem with this code is can not measure view holder items correctly.

Comment: @MohammadRezaEram yes, the code relays on correctly preforms method `viewHolder.itemView.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec)`. But it's outsied the onMeasure()

Comment: Is there a way to make dynamic width horizontal grid view or not or you didn't find too? I think leanback is the worst android library from google with zero extend compatibility.

Comment: I don't find nothing better then in answer. Leanback seems to be abounded. So we abounded leanback. And re-implement all using standard libraries.

Comment: Then how you did handle focus and navigation problems with D-pad? it's hard without leanback widget. do you have any open-source widgets or projects that implemented in this way?

Comment: @MohammadRezaEram From android 8 the focus works quiet good. On Android 9 is even better. But in same odd cases we need to implement searchFocus and findFocus methods. Also we use xml tag params nextUpFocus and so on.
But I think it was worth it.

Comment: It will not wrap properly if you add horizontal space to `HorizontalGridView` programmatically using `setHorizontalSpacing()`

Answer (score 2):

setRowHeight method can be used to achieve it:

```
gridView.setRowHeight(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
```

In my case I extend HorizontalGridView and call this method in constructor to make WRAP_CONTENT default behavior